# Adding array as a source to jQuery autocomplete

Tags: jquery, asp.net, autocomplete

I need to supply my autocomplete from a webservice who passes an array into the autocomplete source.

Here is my webservice:

```
    public Filter[] getAutoComplete(string column)
    {
        List<Filter> list = new List<Filter>();

        DbAccess dbacc = new DbAccess();

          DataTable dt = dbacc.getColumnHeader(column);

          Filter _Filter = new Filter();


          if (column == "member_id")
          {
              foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
              {
                  _Filter.memid = row["member_id"].ToString();
              }
          }
          else if (column == "lname")
          {
              foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
              {
                  _Filter.memid = row["lname"].ToString();
              }
          }
          else if (column == "mname")
          {
              foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
              {
                  _Filter.memid = row["mname"].ToString();
              }
          }
          else if (column == "fname")
          {
              foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
              {
                  _Filter.memid = row["fname"].ToString();
              }
          }

        list.Add(_Filter);

        return list.ToArray();
    }
```

And here is my jquery ajax:

$.ajax({

```
    url: "webservices/wbFilters.asmx/getAutoComplete",
    data: json,
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function (mydata) {

        $("#tags").autocomplete({
            source: mydata
        });

    }
});
```

I can verify that my list array has a value. I just couldn't attach it to my autocomplete. I read that I can add a array as a source but I really can't get it to work.

Can someone please explain what needs to be done to get this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For custom data sources that hold more than a list of strings, you need to specify the property or properties you want to display. Therefore you need to override the _renderItem, like so:

```
$("#tags").autocomplete({
    source: myData
}).data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
    return $( "<li></li>" )
            .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
            .append( "<a>" + item.memid + "</a>" )
            .appendTo( ul );
};
```

For detailed info, see: http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#custom-data

Comment: Now there's something. But it is undefined.

Comment: Maybe you need to combine my answer with Dappergoat's and use myData.d.

Comment: I actually did that. Still now working. I'm getting undefined results.

Comment: Then you should try to debug what **is** in _myData_ or _item_.

Comment: I finally got it to work. Thank you guys. One more question. After entering a second character, the autocomplete hides. Is there a length or something that I should set to change this?

Comment: Hmmm... Weird that it closes. What was the solution?

Comment: .append( "<a>" + item.memid + "</a>" ) -- the name of the item is incorrect. I gave the wrong copy of my code. Thanks Credits also to Dappergoat! Regarding my question before your question, do you have an answer to that?

Comment: No, I'm sorry. I don't know why that happens.

Comment: It's okay. Thank you again. By the way, my auto complete results seems to be not clickable. Is there a way to make it clickable?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing your Success function to this:

```
 success: function (mydata) {

        $("#tags").autocomplete({
            source: mydata.d
        });

    }
```

it is my experience that .net wraps the json object in a parameter called "d"

Comment: Have you tried this in compbination with Jeroens answer? I've recently made a autocomplete feature like that

Answer (score 0):

This worked great for me and it follows the api at jquery.

```
$("#Dialogs_ProjectID").autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Log.aspx/jQuery_Get_Autocomplete",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: JSON.stringify({
                columnName: "Project",
                startsWith: request.term
            }),
            success: function (data) {
                response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                    return {
                        value: item
                    }
                }));
            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(errorThrown);
            }
        });
    }

});
```